# how to make two layer ssh tunnel for browsing

Tags: proxy, ssh, socks, tunnel, http-tunneling

I know how to make a one layer tunnel:

```
ssh -ND 9898 username@mymachine
```

and then add a sockss proxy `localhost:9898` in the browser.

but how to make a two layer tunnel? Suppose `mymachine` is not directly accessible to me but another machine `machineprime` is accessible and `mymachine` is accessible once I am on `machineprime`. So how do I redirect all my browser requests via `machineprime` and `mymachine` to the outer world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links helped me achieve what I wanted:

- [SSH as socks proxy through multiple hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/280129/http-proxy-over-ssh-not-socks)
- [http proxy over ssh, not socks](https://superuser.com/questions/332850/ssh-as-socks-proxy-through-multiple-hosts)